# How to remove "wp-content/uploads/2019/10" from media file URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

For a current project, I am supposed to remove "/uploads/2019/10" from specific media file URLs. For instance, I need this, "https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/myAwesomedoc.pdf", to be "https://www.mywebsite.com/myAwesomedoc.pdf". How can I accomplish this?

BACKGROUND: This needs to be done only for PDFs on the site. So far, I've tried redirects, through plugins (Pretty Link) and via .htaccess file per the direction of a peer but this didn't work because redirects don't change the actual "home" URL.

I've read elsewhere that in wp-config.php that I can insert code like `define( 'UPLOADS', 'files' );` but this would affect all files, not to mention I would need to relocate all PDFs to this new folder called "files".

Lastly, I'm aware that under *Settings*>*Media* , I can disable the *uploads* folder from sorting in YYYY/MM format.

Here are an example of what I produced in .htaccess for redirects

```
# New redirects
redirect 307 /wp-content/uploads/2019/10/myAwesomedoc.pdf /myAwesomedoc.pdf
```

This wasn't fruitful as, unlike redirect plugins, this made the file system look for a file called "myAwesomedoc.pdf" in the root file, which of course didn't exist.

After the "redirect link" method wasn't satisfactory, I attempted to go the "wp-config.php" route and with what I found, I wasn't able to find a way to only change the various paths a PDF file may have on this website [e.g., "https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/myAwesomedoc.pdf", "https://www.mywebsite.com/projects/assignments/myAwesomedoc.pdf", "https://www.mywebsite.com/products/documents/myAwesomedoc.pdf"].

I appreciate any help I may get on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you got confused between Redirection and Url rewriting!
There is a possible way of doing that with .Htaccess by matching pdf extensions with regex and pointing them to the real path in media directory. 
But some anomalies would happen cause of different dates patterns used by wordpress!

I think Redirection wouldn't solve the issue unless files are already moved to root directory.
How about you write your own plugin for this feature?

- Would this feature be shared with other users (editors, contributors...)?

For PDF files you don't any media processing functionalities (resizing...)
 So The plugin would:
- upload files "Safely"  to root folder. 
- List only pdf files

It depends on how you are publishing those PDFs.. If they are meant for download only then you just share their links. 
Otherwise with a viewer or extra information , you could define a custom post type for those docs and use custom fields...

Then you redirect old files urls to new location.

Comment: I appreciate this well thought out response. 

This feature may potentially be shared with other admin.


I believe all the PDFs in question are merely for downloading/viewing, nothing more.

Regardless, I will have to definitely consider this approach! I have never created my own plugin so this may be too advanced for myself but I'll bring this up to my superiors.

Comment: I just edited my answer to explain the Url rewriting approach. Yes.. Such plugin is easy to do for an experienced developer and he must be aware of security threats especially on root directory ;)